# The divisor of a local equation of a hypersurface is the hypersurface in certain open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral and normal scheme and $D=[Y]$ an irreducible Weil divisor of $X$. Suppose that $x\in X$ is such that $x\in Y$ and the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ corresponding to $Y$ is principal, generated by $f\in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ such that we may understand $f\in\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{X})$. I want to prove that 
$$
D|_{U}=\mathrm{div}|_{U}(f).
$$
It is clear that $D|_{U}=[Y\cap U]$ and that $\mathrm{div}|_U(f)\geq 0$. How do we know that $\mathrm{div}|_{U}(f)$ is precisely $[Y\cap U]$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. $\text{div}_{|U}(f)$ is by definition the formal sum with multiplicities of codimension 1 irreducible varieties such that $f$ vanishes along them. Since $f$ is holomorphic, there are no poles so $\text{div}|_{U}(f)$ is effective, i.e the coefficients are positive. On the other hand, by definition $\{f = 0\} \cap U = Y \cap U$ so $Y$ is the only irreducible codim 1 variety where $f$ vanishes, i.e $D_{|U} = \text{div}|_{U}(f)$.

Comment: Dear @N.H., $\mathrm{div}|_U(f)$ is the restriction of $\mathrm{div}(f)$ to those irreducible hypersurfaces $W$ such that $W\cap U\neq \varnothing$. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$. How do we know that $f$ is the generator of $\mathfrak{m}_{\eta}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$? Thank you.

Comment: Ok I don't use langage of generic point much, but I guess $\eta$ is the zero ideal of $\mathfrak p$. In this case, recall that $O_{X, \eta}$ is by definition $O_X$ localized at $\mathfrak p$. This is a so-called local ring, and its maximal ideal is $\mathfrak p {O_X}_{\mathfrak p}$. So $f$ is the generator of $\mathfrak m_{\eta}$.

Comment: what do you mean by "such that we may understand $f\in\Gamma(U,O_X)$"? Are you assuming $X$ is integral?

Comment: Dear @user347489, thank you for pointing that out. I will add "integral" to the hypothesis.